# Is there a more friendly RefCell-like object?

Tags: vector, rust

I'm looking for a class much like `Vec<RefCell<T>>`, in that it is the ultimate owner & allocator of all of its data, yet different pieces of the array can be be mutably borrowed by multiple parties indefinitely.

I emphasize **indefinitely** because of course pieces of `Vec<T>` can also be mutably borrowed by multiple parties, but doing so involves making a split which can only be resolved after the parties are done borrowing.

`Vec<RefCell<T>>` seems to be a world of danger and many ugly `if` statements checking `borrow_state`, which seems to be [unstable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_state).  If you do something wrong, then kablammo!  Panic!  This is not what a lending library is like.  In a lending library, if you ask for a book that isn't there, they tell you "Oh, it's checked out."  Nobody dies in an explosion.

So I would like to write code something like this:

```
let mut a = LendingLibrary::new();
a.push(Foo{x:10});
a.push(Foo{x:11});
let b1 = a.get(0); // <-- b1 is an Option<RefMut<Foo>>
let b2 = a.get(1); // <-- b2 is an Option<RefMut<Foo>>

// the 0th element has already been borrowed, so...
let b3 = a.get(0); // <-- b3 is Option::None
```

Does such a thing exist?  Or is there another canonical way to get this kind of behavior?  A kind of "friendly RefCell"?

If the answer happens to be yes, is there also a threadsafe variant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RefCell` is not designed for long-lived borrows. The typical use case is that in a function, you'll borrow the `RefCell` (either mutably or immutably), work with the value, then release the borrow before returning. I'm curious to know how you're hoping to recover from a borrowed `RefCell` in a single-threaded context.

The thread-safe equivalent to `RefCell` is [`RwLock`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html). It has `try_read` and `try_write` functions that do not block or panic if an incompatible lock is still acquired (on any thread, including the current thread). Contrarily to `RefCell`, it makes sense to just retry later if locking a `RwLock` fails, since another thread might just happen to have locked it at the same time.

If you end up always using `write` or `try_write`, and never `read` or `try_read`, then you should probably use the simpler [`Mutex`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
#![feature(borrow_state)]
use std::cell::{RefCell, RefMut, BorrowState};

struct LendingLibrary<T> {
    items: Vec<RefCell<T>>
}

impl<T> LendingLibrary<T> {
    fn new(items: Vec<T>) -> LendingLibrary<T> {
        LendingLibrary {
            items: items.into_iter().map(|e| RefCell::new(e)).collect()
        }
    }

    fn get(&self, item: usize) -> Option<RefMut<T>> {
        self.items.get(item)
            .and_then(|cell| match cell.borrow_state() {
                BorrowState::Unused => Some(cell.borrow_mut()),
                _ => None
            })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let lib = LendingLibrary::new(vec![1, 2, 3]);

    let a = lib.get(0); // Some
    let b = lib.get(1); // Some

    let a2 = lib.get(0); // None
}
```

This currently requires a nightly release to work.